# Kotlin make adapter more reusable

Tags: java, android, class, kotlin, annotations

I use multiple recyclerview adapters within my app and interface to listen to onclicks.
I come to the point where I have 2 fragments which displays the exact same views and exact same data only within another class. But the clickListener within the adapter is bound to the first class so the second class value is not accepted.

This is the code to make more sense.

```
class ContactsAdapter(
    var listVar: RealmResults<SchemeContacts>?,
    val autoUpdate: Boolean,
    val cellClickListener: ContactsList
) : RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<SchemeContacts, ChatsAdapter.DataHolder>(listVar, autoUpdate)...
```

I use it in the following class ContactsList.

```
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    adapter = ContactsAdapter(contacts, true, this@ContactsList)
```

When i want re use it my ChatsClass like this:

```
   layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    adapter = ContactsAdapter(contacts, true, this@ChatsClass)
```

I get an error because it doesn't match the giving annotation, which is correct.
How can I make sure it accepts both classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can easily solve this using interfaces. I haven't tested the code but it should work.

First define an interface

```
interface ContactItemClickListener {
   fun onClick(contact: Contact)
}
```

Use this interface in your adapter

```
class ContactsAdapter(
    var listVar: RealmResults<SchemeContacts>?,
    val autoUpdate: Boolean,
    val cellClickListener: ContactItemClickListener
) : RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<SchemeContacts, ChatsAdapter.DataHolder>(listVar, autoUpdate)
```

Then in your ContactList class use it like this

```
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    adapter = ContactsAdapter(contacts, true, object: ContactItemClickListener {
        override fun onClick(contact: Contact) {
           // handle your click here
        }
    })
```

And in your Chats class use it like this

```
   layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    adapter = ContactsAdapter(contacts, true, object: ContactItemClickListener {
        override fun onClick(contact: Contact) {
           // handle your click here
        }
   })
```

Comment: I get Mismatch with the following message:
Required:
ContactsAdapter.ContactItemClickListener
Found:
([ERROR :  ]) → Unit .

I get a suggestion to change it to Any but then I will lose my onclick function.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I was using lambda in the Adapter's constructor. I have updated the answer and it should work now.

Comment: Thank you @Susan Thapa for the changes, I made also some small changes to my bindholder and it works fine now. Thx for your time.